# Call render template variable on button click in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a method where, I wanted to call the variable only when a button is clicked

```
@app.route("/select", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def select_data():
    return render_template('select.html', select_csv = select_csv())
```

This is the variable i wanted to call, `select_csv = select_csv()`

This is the html,

```
<input type="button" value={{ subscription_csv }}>
```

The moment get into the html page, the variable gets called,
rather i wanted to call the variable only once the button is clicked.

Complete html,

```
<form action = "/select" method="POST">

    <div class = "subscription_report">
    <label for = "Month_From"> Month From </label>
    <input type="month" id = "Month_From" name  = "Month_From" />

    <label for = "Month_To"> Month To </label>
    <input type="month" id = "Month_To" name  = "Month_To" />

    <label for = "submit"></label>
    <button type = "Submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>

<img src="static/images/subscription_monthly_report.jpg" width="1250" height="500" />

<table>
......
</table>

<form>
    <button type="button" value = {{ select_csv  }}>Download</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a problem in refreshing the page when the button in clicked then you can call the route again when button is clicked and place a condition in the route.

```
@app.route("/select/<clicked>", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def select_data(clicked=False):
     return render_template('select.html', select_csv=select_csv() if clicked else None)
```

Now in html call the same route onclick:

```
href="{{url_for('app.select_data', clicked=1)}}"
```

Comment: Page is not getting rendered with this solution. ```The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.```

Comment: you need to send in clicked=0 or clicked=1 if you are using url_for. otherwise flask wont find the url.  url_for('app.select_data', clicked=1)

Comment: I did that. Provided clicked parameter to the url ```url_for('app.select_data', clicked=1)```, it is providing error even after that.  Probably because i have two variables in the render_template method ```return render_template('select.html', data=data(), select_csv=select_csv() if clicked else None)```. Is there a way to handle this

Comment: Did you provide the clicked parameter in all route calls not only for the anchor or button?    if you're typing it manually call "rooturl/select/1" or 0

Comment: Yes I did that. But the page is not getting rendered

Comment: It is working on my end. if you wanna share more or your code and the error, I may be able to help you.

Comment: I have provided complete html code. Let me know what would be the right modifications

Comment: the issue is i have two variables in the render template ``` return render_template('select.html', select_data = select_data(),  select_csv=select_csv() if clicked else None) ``` The process is trying to call ```select_data()``` as well when clicked and then it is failing.